# angular ng serve ng build error compiling app ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError: expected "}"

Tags: angular, npm, node-sass

I tried with all possible nodejs version and npm via nvm, I tried to downgrade/upgrade ng core and ng cli tried to install sass-node and removed sass and vice versa nothing seems to work.
I've googled all stack overflow question there are many very similar to mine but nothing seems to solve

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and testing this will work: assuming this environment

- node -v
- v14.20.1
- npm -v
- 9.1.2
- git --version
- git version 2.34.1

after you successfull npm install all the packages without errors just:

- npm uninstall sass
- npm uninstall node-sass
- npm install node-sass@4.14.1

and then ng serve build or whatever

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it happened because I deleted a scss variable, so when it compiled it had something like:

```
height: ;
```

Debugging wasn't easy but I managed to disable minification and optimization modifiying angular.json
with:
https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-configuration

```
"optimization": {
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": {
    "minify": false,
    "inlineCritical": false
  },
  "fonts": true
}
```

Then I searched for the style created by `ng build` in the dist folder and pasted on a editor that showed me the error.